# Confused about unistd_XX.h

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm trying to get the constants of all syscalls but there appears to be a huge mess between `include/asm/unistd.h`, `include/asm/unistd_XX.h` and `include/asm-generic/unistd.h` in kernel's source.

What is the difference between each one of them?

Which one should I use if I want to get:

```
a) x86 syscalls
b) x64 syscalls
c) IA32 emulation syscalls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the right way is using `unistd.h` for `x64` and/or `unistd_32.h` for `x86` and `ia32`.
Those files are in the headers of your linux distro. but keep in mind that the path changes between distros (and even between kernels), so the best way to find out *where* exactly those files are is:

```
uni_hack.h

#if defined(CONFIG_X86)  <---- replace with whatever you want, #ifdef CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION for example
#   include <asm/unistd_32.h>
#endif
```

-

```
Kbuild file

obj-m += kernel_module_example.o

$(obj)/kernel_module_example.o: $(obj)/real_unistd.h

$(obj)/real_unistd.h: $(src)/uni_hack.h FORCE
    cpp $(c_flags) -E -dM <$< >$@  <---- this will generate "real_unistd.h" in the directory of your kernel module, and it will contain the content of unistd_32.h
```

Using the `unistd.h` for `x64` is just a matter on `#include`-ing it in your source code.